# Mixing primary Rust crate with workspaces (sub-crates) as sub-directories

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a bin crate with a standard Rust crate structure.  I would like to add a few more lib crates to the same repo, without moving the existing code to a sub-directory.  It seems `Cargo.toml` can have both the `workspaces` and regular values in the same file, but I couldn't find any documentation for such usage, or if there are any issues with this dir structure:

```
/myapp
|- Cargo.toml
|- src/
|- lib1/
|    |- Cargo.toml
|    |- src/
|- lib2/
|    |- Cargo.toml
|    |- src/
```

the top-level Cargo.toml for the myapp crate would have this content:

```ini
[workspace]
members = ["lib1", "lib2"]

[package]
name = "myapp"
version = "0.1"
edition = "2021"
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view documentation for [The Manifest Format](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html) and [Workspaces](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/workspaces.html) in the Cargo Book. The latter describes two expected uses of workspaces:

> ### The [workspace] section
>
> To create a workspace, you add the `[workspace]` table to a `Cargo.toml`:
>
> ```toml
> [workspace]
> # ...
> ```
>
> At minimum, a workspace has to have a member, either with a root package or as a virtual manifest.
>
> #### Root package
>
> If the `[workspace]` section is added to a `Cargo.toml` that already defines a `[package]`, the package is the root package of the workspace. The workspace root is the directory where the workspace's `Cargo.toml` is located.
>
> ```toml
> [workspace]
>
> [package]
> name = "hello_world" # the name of the package
> version = "0.1.0"    # the current version, obeying semver
> authors = ["Alice <a@example.com>", "Bob <b@example.com>"]
> ```
>
> #### Virtual workspace
>
> Alternatively, a `Cargo.toml` file can be created with a `[workspace]` section but without a `[package]` section. This is called a *virtual manifest*. This is typically useful when there isn't a "primary" package, or you want to keep all the packages organized in separate directories.
>
> ```toml
> # [PROJECT_DIR]/Cargo.toml
> [workspace]
> members = ["hello_world"]
> ```
>
> ```toml
> # [PROJECT_DIR]/hello_world/Cargo.toml
> [package]
> name = "hello_world" # the name of the package
> version = "0.1.0"    # the current version, obeying semver
> authors = ["Alice <a@example.com>", "Bob <b@example.com>"]
> ```

So yes, extending your existing `Cargo.toml` to support more packages is expected and will work just fine.

I think the only thing to keep in mind that you may have in your existing `Cargo.toml` that will affect your new member `Cargo.toml`s as well is any `[patch]`, `[replace]`, or `[profile.*]` sections. In [Overriding Dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html) and [Profiles](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html) they say:

> Cargo only looks at the {patch settings / replace settings / profiles} in the `Cargo.toml` manifest at the root of the workspace. {Patch settings / Replace settings / Profiles} defined in dependencies will be ignored.